# HTML5 Canvas Elements as Objects

Tags: html, canvas

I want to convert an old actionscript game to HTML5. I like the approach that AS3 gives you, in that each element you draw on your canvas is an object, of which you can manipulate, such as performing actions and animations on.

Straight canvas does not seem to give you this ability, but I was hoping that there was a framework that has abstracted the HTML5 canvas, and given it this extra power.

Comment: Look into the JavaScript port of cocos2d, it might be about what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can create constructor functions for constructing the elements you need to make, and you can create action methods in the constructor, that way you will have all kinds of possibilities available to you depending on the element and it's actions.

Example of a Ball constructor function:

```
// Ball constructor
var Ball = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.radius = 10;
    this.color = '#fff';

    // Direction and min, max x,y
    this.dX = 15;
    this.dY = -15;

    this.minX = this.minY = 20 + this.radius;
    this.maxX = this.radius - (canvasWidth - 20);
    this.maxY = this.radius + canvasHeight;

    this.draw = function(ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, twoPI, true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.save();
            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
    };
};
```

Use it like:

```
// CREATE THE BALL
ball = new Ball(centerX, canvasHeight - paddle.height - 30);
ball.draw(ctx);
```

Comment: but if I wanted an onclick event on a specific element, so that I could execute the specific method on.